# What is a address space of process?

Tags: unix

Please any body tell what is meant by address space ?
why it is called like that ?
and also about the virtual memory ?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Pavankumar

Answer (score 4):

I think *address space* refers to a [segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segment).

In real mode (intel's XT and 286) segment is just a way to make a program independent of it's space in memory. When a program gets compiled the addresses (of varables, labels - functions) are hardcoded into a program. - This way it would be difficult to load two programs at the same time, because they would all want to use the same addresses.

We need to use **relative addresses** instead of *absolute* ones. The resolution between the relative and physical addresses are made relative to **segments**. If one program is loaded starting from the segment `0x200` and another program is loaded starting from `0x600` they can freely use the same address (for example `0x41`) because that will be relative to their respective segments. In our case (real mode) the segment `0x200` will be translated to physical address `0x2000` (through multiplying it by `0x10`) and after adding the relative address, the resulting physical address will be `0x2041`.

There are many segments which can be used. Data operations by default are made relative to the program's **Data Segment** (held in the `DS` register of the cpu) and code operations are made relative to **Code Sement** (held in the `CS` register). Stack addresses are resolved to physical addresses using the **Stack Segment** (`SS` register).

But in real mode you can freely use the segments, you can access other program's segments or enter arbitrary values which will be resolved to arbitrary physical addresses.

In protected mode the whole concept changed. Segments do not hold addresses any more. They hold **selectors**. They only refer to an element in a table, where the real base addresses are held. The table also contains limits, so you can no longer address ANY physical address, only inside the portion of memory which was given to your program by the OS. This introduces the concept of ownership of memory blocks by processes.

I think this is enough for the start, feel free to read more on either [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) or other good sources. The topic is quite documented.